# Which language (Python vs Julia) is preferable for large scale mathematical optimization?

Tags: optimization, python

I am into electricity planning research and it can become a bi-level mixed-integer stochastic problem with large number of scenarios and would need decomposition techniques for solution tractability. I am wondering if I should go with python or julia as speed and existing code-base will help me get up to the speed.

Comment: Python has more packages, Julia is aiming to be faster (and can be). But translation between the two isn't that painful, and moreover, for the majority of people, the milliseconds shaved off does not actually matter

Comment: "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" echoes about in my head